# When building links for SEO should you link to the http or https version of your site?

Tags: seo, https

My website redirects all versions (http, www etc.) to an https/non www version, as most websites do.

When I am building links for SEO should I aim to get links to the https version of the website, or does it not matter?

My understanding is a 301 will only pass ~95% of link equity.

Comment: From a security standpoint you should link to HTTPS.   Linking to HTTP when it redirects to HTTPS only gives the links a chance to get tracked or maliciously changed.

Comment: 301 from HTTP to HTTPS is not treated the same as 301 `/url-to/` `/new-url/`, its a protocol switch and the decay in juice is not the same, Google wants to reward for SSL, not punish. But as @StephenOstermiller has mentioned, HTTPS is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[John Mueller](https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/PY1xCWbeDVC) Post

> Do I lose "link juice" from the redirects? 
>   No, for 301 or 302 redirects from HTTP to HTTPS no PageRank is lost

So Simon's comment is really true and I agree with Stephen's comment as well.

By adding HTTP link on other blog comments, you're just making extra load on your server, because there is 301 redirection in middle, which server handle it automatically (whenever Googlebot crawl your HTTP backlink), and it require some  CPU resources.

You can see example of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com in this [website](http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php). It will add extra 154 bytes on every new request.